# Scroll down flutter modal bottomsheet with a scrollview in the sheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I use the flutter function showmodalbottomsheet to display a page with a customscroll view.

But I have a problem when the scroll of the scrollview is overscrolling I wanted to scroll the the bottomsheet instead of overscrolling the customscrollview.

How can I choose which scroll I want to use?

for example I want to do like Facebook commentary page:

[image: here you can see the sheet is scrolling down when the scrollview is at max scroll]

Answer (score 5):

What you probably need is `DraggableScrollableSheet` .

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
    builder: (context, scrollController) => SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            height: 100,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            height: 300,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            height: 300,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

(I was also looking for an answer when I stumbled upon your question, decided to share the results of my research :) hope it helps you!)

Comment: For this to work properly, you also need to set `minChildSize: 1,` and `initialChildSize: 1,` on the `DraggableScrollableSheet` component.

Comment: @AkinjiolaToni If you set the `minChildSize: 1` as soon as you start scrolling, the bottom sheet closes. `0.75` would be a good idea. I checked this on iOS, not sure about Android.